# kendo ui auto complete + virtualization + remove duplicate values

Tags: autocomplete, kendo-ui, virtualization

I want to remove the already added items from autocomplete list after server side filtering has been completed. I achieve the same using data method and remove items from the data received from the server. it is working fine when virtualization I off.

As soon as I implemented the virtualization the request for filter data has been started posting on the server in an infinite loop. I suspect that it is happening due to the page size is larger than the number of records in the data as we remove some data from the list and a total number of records is greater than the page size.

Is there any way to achieve the desired behavior?